# Entity framework query designer

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

SQL Server has great query designer that enable me to write every complex queries easily.
recently I'm involving with Entity framework. I know it has three ways to querying data.

1. LINQ to Entites
2. Entity SQL
3. Query Method

Is there any query designer for Entity framework like SQL query Designer ?
I'm familiar with [LINQ PAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) and also [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vlinq) LINQ query Designer(I was unable to use this software in windows 7 64 bit).
what are your suggestions?

Comment: My opinion is that using designer to define queries is for creating simple queries by people who are not very familiar with SQL yet. I hardly believe that you can do really complex and optimal query in the designer. My suggestion is: don't use query designers and learn how to write SQL and Linq queries directly.

Comment: @Ladislav: You can save a lot of time by using a query designer, you can reduce complexity and you can prevent careless mistakes(missing braces f.e.) with designers. That has nothing to do with your actual skills in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQPad is probably one of the best. I really like that is shows me what the SQL was that was generated from my LINQ query and I can even look at the IL code.

It doesn't have a graphical designer like the SQL Query Designer and this isn't a bad thing. If you really want something like that you may as well just have that tool generate the SQL for you. LINQ is querying data in C# and if you're querying the database then this is an abstraction. A graphical designer for LINQ would be like layering a layer on top of an abstraction. There would be even more places the interpretation could go wrong and the SQL Query Designer is far from perfect. I can't tell you how many times at my work people bring queries built with that tool to me and complain something doesn't work and I see that they have multiple joins that are just incorrect or subqueries that make no sense.